# Unique subfield of cyclotomic field extension of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> If $\zeta$ is a primitive $p$th root of 1 ($p\geq 3$), then there is a unique subfield $K\subset\Bbb Q(\zeta)$ such that $[K:\Bbb Q] = 2$.

I know the existence of such $K$ by Galois theory, but I don't know how to prove the uniqueness. From Galois theory, the corresponding Galois group of $K$ is $H<(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ which is a cyclic group and $|H|=\frac{p-1}{2}$. Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: $H=Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)/K)$ is a subgroup with $(p-1)/2$ elements, it is unique, and $K$ is the subfield fixed by $H$

Comment: @reuns Why the subgroup with $(p-1)/2$ element is unique ?

Comment: Because the subgroups of $\Bbb{Z/nZ}$ are the $\Bbb{dZ/nZ}$ for $d|n$ (which follows from that every subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$ is of the form $d\Bbb{Z}$ which follows from $a\Bbb{Z}+b\Bbb{Z}=\gcd(a,b)\Bbb{Z}$)

Comment: @reuns Oh, right. Thanks.